# unix:find files that start with capital

Tags: unix

Basically,i want to copy files from one directory to another.The condition is that the file must not have as first letter a capital and must end in (.txt).
(This is my first question in stackoverflow so be gentle )

Comment: "How do I copy files in unix?" is not a programming question; it's user support.

Comment: yeah it could be questioned in a better way,but you understand what i want melpomene

Comment: @andrikoulas Yes, you want us to give you a command you can use to copy certain files. User support.

Answer (score 0):

This do the trick `cp [a-z]*.txt directory`

Comment: yeah.i take file1.txt fil3.txt but File1.txt too

Comment: `cp [^(A-Z)]*.txt direc` try this, is exactly the same

Comment: -bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('
that's what i get

Comment: trying removing the parenthesis

Comment: In some locales, such as en_US, [a-z] will include uppercase A through Y as well.  http://teaching.idallen.org/net2003/06w/notes/character_sets.txt